# Aligning a table to the second column of another table

Tags: html, css

I want to align the second `<table>` in the `<div>`. The table should start from the second column of the first table. Right now, the second table with the text “1111111111111” starts from the extreme left but I wish to align it to where the textboxes start in the first table.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div style="float: left; height: 250px;overflow:auto; display:block;margin-left: 10px">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left: 10px; font-size: 24px;text-align: center" colspan="2">Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <asp:Label runat="server">First Name</asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px">
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <asp:Label runat="server">Email</asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px">
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 45px;"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 20px; word-wrap: break-word;text-align: center">1111111111111</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just have multiple `tbody` elements in the table?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `margin-left` value to `33%` for the 2nd table using `:nth-child(2)`

```css
table:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left; height: 250px;overflow:auto; display:block;margin-left: 10px">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left: 10px; font-size: 24px;text-align: center" colspan="2">Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <asp:Label runat="server">First Name</asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px">
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <asp:Label runat="server">Email</asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px">
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 45px;"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 20px; word-wrap: break-word;text-align: center">1111111111111</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: In stylesheet file. Create a new file and link it in the head, or use internal CSS. I recommend former though.

Comment: i tried but its still not giving correct output as you have you when i run code snippet.

Comment: Not sure how you are using it. Can you post the implemented code in http://plnkr.co/?

Comment: Check this: http://plnkr.co/edit/fr1oJquWwl7LgGpRFQXA?p=preview index.html and style.css file on the left

Comment: It's because your code is dynamic. You need to adjust the output. we have all posted solutions for your static code.

Comment: What is dynamic in it?

Comment: Check your version of code and mine. Are they same? Table borders are not generated and input is missing in the second table.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  display: table;      /* Display the div as a table */
}
div > table {
  display: contents;   /* Ignore the tables and display their contents
                          as if they were contents of the div */
}
div > table:last-child tr:before {
  content: '';         /* Insert a pseudo-element at the beginning */
  display: table-cell; /* Display it as a cell */
}
```

```css
div {
  display: table;
}
div > table {
  display: contents;
}
div > table:last-child tr:before {
  content: '';
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border="1">
    <caption>Title</caption>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>1111111111111</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note `display: contents` is not widely supported yet.

Comment: I would use `div > table { display: table-row-group }` instead of `display: contents` but the parser inserts an annoying `tbody` element. An alternative would be removing it with JS.

Comment: Not giving exact output.  The text 111  should align textbox

Comment: @Happy I think your browser doesn't support `display: contents`. Try it with Firefox 37+

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this code. Let me know if its working with you.

http://jsfiddle.net/FnK9D/13/

```
<div style="position:absolute;">

  <table border="1" style="">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left: 10px; font-size: 24px;text-align: center" colspan="2">Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <asp:Label runat="server">First Name</asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px">
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <asp:Label runat="server">Email</asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td style="padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px">
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 45px;"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>



  <table border="1" style="float:right;">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 20px; word-wrap: break-word;text-align: center">1111111111111111</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: nope. the text 111 should align to textbox on left. curretly u are aligning table to right. See the first answer and thats how i want

Comment: still wrong. I want like this http://plnkr.co/edit/fr1oJquWwl7LgGpRFQXA?p=preview